# What is the alternative of '.orient()' in the new D3 API?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In D3 old API, there was a `orient()` function which changes ticks position along axes, like `d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("top")`

The result of above code is this: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByJwk0csqIvZOUd3Ml8wUHhGTG8

However, in [new API](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis) I am unable to find similar method. Is there any alternative method for accomplishing the similar task?

Comment: I edited your title removing the references to the scale. That method belongs to the axis generator instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) is clear about the changes:

> D3 4.0 provides default styles and shorter syntax. In place of d3.svg.axis and axis.orient, D3 4.0 now provides four constructors for each orientation: d3.axisTop, d3.axisRight, d3.axisBottom, d3.axisLeft.

Therefore, this v3 syntax:

```
d3.svg.axis.scale(scale).orient("top");
```

Should be this in v4:

```
d3.axisTop(scale);
```

According to the API, `d3.axisTop(scale)`:

> Constructs a new top-oriented axis generator for the given scale, with empty tick arguments, a tick size of 6 and padding of 3. In this orientation, ticks are drawn above the horizontal domain path.

Here is a very simple demo comparing `d3.axisTop()` with `d3.axisBottom()`. The first axis uses `d3.axisTop()`, while the second one uses `d3.axisBottom()`:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var orientations = ["axisTop", "axisBottom"];
var gX = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(orientations)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", (d, i) => "translate(0," + (50 + 50 * i) + ")")
  .each(function(d) {
    d3.select(this).call(d3[d](d3.scaleLinear().range([10, 290])))
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```